# Creating Dynamic button with click event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create a dynamic button with a click event with JavaScript?

I tried this, but when I click the add button, an alert message show up! It's not what I want - I want to be able to click the button which is dynamically created.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function add(type) {
        //Create an input type dynamically.   
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        //Assign different attributes to the element. 
        element.setAttribute("type", type);
        element.setAttribute("value", type);
        element.setAttribute("name", type);
        element.setAttribute("onclick", alert("blabla"));

        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
        //Append the element in page (in span).  
        foo.appendChild(element);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Pure javascript? (it's easier to use an js library like jQuery)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Wow you're close. Edits in comments:

```js
function add(type) {
  //Create an input type dynamically.   
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  //Assign different attributes to the element. 
  element.type = type;
  element.value = type; // Really? You want the default value to be the type string?
  element.name = type; // And the name too?
  element.onclick = function() { // Note this is a function
    alert("blabla");
  };

  var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
  //Append the element in page (in span).  
  foo.appendChild(element);
}
document.getElementById("btnAdd").onclick = function() {
  add("text");
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Text Field">
<p id="fooBar">Fields:</p>
```

Now, instead of setting the `onclick` property of the element, which is called "DOM0 event handling," you might consider using [`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) (on most browsers) or [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (on all but very recent Microsoft browsers) — you'll have to detect and handle both cases — as that form, called "DOM2 event handling," has more flexibility. But if you don't need multiple handlers and such, the old DOM0 way works fine.

---

Separately from the above: You might consider using a good JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over browsers differences like the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` thing, provide useful utility features, and various other things. Obviously there's nothing a library can do that you can't do without one, as the libraries are just JavaScript code. But when you use a good library with a broad user base, you get the benefit of a *huge* amount of work already done by other people dealing with those browsers differences, etc.

Comment: @mekici - Note, this answer had a stray `)` on the `alert()` line, which I removed. This was a simple mistake. Please read the entire answer.

Comment: @mekici - And see http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute and using the `setAttribute()` method. I have, personally, never trusted it.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me :D

Answer (score 6):

this:

```
element.setAttribute("onclick", alert("blabla"));
```

should be:

```
element.onclick = function () {
  alert("blabla");
}
```

Because you call alert instead push alert as string in attribute

Comment: No no *no*. It should be `el.onclick=function(){}`.

Comment: element.setAttribute("onclick", 'alert("blabla")');

Comment: @mekici - When you use the form in that comment, you're using `eval()` to evaluate the `alert()`. This is generally considered a Bad Idea (both in performance and security). Using an anonymous function set to the handler (as neworld has and T.J. Crowder have) is the accepted best practice.

Comment: Yes your solution works too! thanks for that!
i didnt check element.setAttribute("onclick", 'alert("blabla")'); 
on chrome but it works on ie9 and mozilla.
@T.J. Crowder's solution doesnt work ie9, mozilla chrome..

Comment: @mekici - That doesn't make any sense. *What part didn't work*?

Answer (score 6):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");

    btn.setAttribute("style","color:red;font-size:23px");

    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    btn.setAttribute("onclick", alert("clicked"));

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an explaination to your code. Code only answers are not welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: @L.Guthardt I am not agree with you. If the code does its job, absence of explanation is not a big deal.

Comment: @yılmaz *Code can only tell you the how, it doesn't tell you the why. That's what you need comments for. [...] While a code-only answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run.* Please have a  look at [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques/148274)

Comment: @L.Guthardt "it doesn't tell you the why" > "sometimes" is missing.

Comment: @yılmaz No it does not. Code can only explain **how** itself works, but not **why** this code works here and why you should choose this code instead of something else.

Comment: @L.Guthardt "sometimes" part is valid for those who can read code.

Comment: @yılmaz I agree.  When I am in trouble, all I need is a tiny code snippet that has been tested by a pioneer who had it working right. One look at it, and I know where my own code went wrong. I don't read lengthy explanations, any way.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to change this line:

```
element.setAttribute("onclick", alert("blabla"));
```

To something like this:

```
element.setAttribute("onclick", function() { alert("blabla"); });
```

Secondly, you may have browser compatibility issues when attaching events that way.  You might need to use .attachEvent / .addEvent, depending on which browser.  I haven't tried manually setting event handlers for a while, but I remember firefox and IE treating them differently.

Comment: You don't need the `setAttribute()` at all.

Comment: there is no name assigned to function. And it will throw error.