# using javascript to dynamically create and delete clickable button with

Tags: javascript

I have created a english to hindi transliteration webpage . 
There are rules for mapping every hindi letter to its english equivalent. 
If user presses 'd' , I want to suggest some nearby letters . It would be great if I am able to create & remove buttons (which have associated onclick action) using javascript.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yeah there are several ways you could do it, depends how you want to implement it

Comment: Here try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707074/creating-dynamic-button-with-click-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steve graham - that worked for creating clickable buttons with asoociated action.
ALso I Used this

```
function removechildren()
{   var node=document.getElementById("fooBar");
    node.innerHTML = "";
}
```

To remove all of them at once.

Comment: how can I remove them one by one when name of child elements is not known ?