# Create buttons dynamically in a div from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that returns the data from the sql...

I need to create buttons in a div called

> divResult

here is my function

```
function retrieveData(transaction, results) {
   for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        var data = results.rows.item(i)['nome'];
        alert(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: More information needed.

Comment: datas from sql ....the relevant for the question is that I need create  buttons in a div called divResult with caption from data ...a string

Comment: for each row I wanna create a button...

Comment: Would do best updating the question. More detail you give better chance of an answer. Tell us wahat part your stuck with and what you have tried. Have you tried to create a button in JS? If so what did you try and what happend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very good answer on how to create html elements using javascript here: [Creating Dynamic button with click event in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707074/creating-dynamic-button-with-click-event-in-javascript).

...I would add this as a simple comment but I don't have enough street cred yet.