# submit <button> doesn't work after an explode before it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked through stackoverflow for days, and none of the stuff I worked. Anyways, after an explosion and appending a submit button to my document the button doesn't alert when clicked.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('hi');
      $("#a").click(function() {
        $(".main, .topbar, button").toggle("explode");
        $('body').delay(8100).append("<img src='picture.png'> <form >  <input            type='text'></form><button id='submit'>submit</button>");
      });
      $("#submit").click(function() {
        alert('hi');

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='a'>button</button>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you event is created before the submit button is available. Create a callback for that and it will work.

Comment: You could also try it like the solution of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707074/creating-dynamic-button-with-click-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are binding `click` to **submit** before **submit** is even added to htmlDOM. To do it that way you have to first add submit to htmlDOM and *then* bind the event handler.

But, for such dynamic elements you can use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function and [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) from any parent element. It is not recommended to delegate from `body`, you can delegate from nearest parent that is present during `document.ready` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert('hi');
      $("#a").click(function() {
        $(".main, .topbar, button").toggle("explode");
        $('body').delay(8100).append("<img src='picture.png'> <form >  <input            type='text'></form><button id='submit'>submit</button>");
      });
      $("body").on('click','#submit',function() {
        alert('hi');

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='a'>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if I understood what you're trying to do there but check if this works:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hi')
            $("#a").click(function () {
                $(".main, .topbar, button").toggle("explode");
                $('body').delay(8100).append("<img src='img.png'> <form >  <input            type='text'><button id='submit'>submit</button></form>");
            });
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                alert('hi');

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are inserting the button after page load, but calling the click handler before the element is on the page. Therefore jQuery can't find your element.

If you want to assign your click handler on page load, that's fine. Just assign your click handler to any parent element that is on the page when the page loads, like `<body>` and then using the jQuery .on() method to specify a descendant selector like so :

```
$('body').on('click', '#submit', function(){ alert('hi'); });
```