# how to make a button dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I am trying to make a dynamically button in javascript

```
    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    button.setAttribute('ID', 'btnSendMailClone');
    button.setAttribute('value', 'Submit');
    button.setAttribute('onclick', 'btnSendMail_Click()');
    button.setAttribute('form', 'myform');
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
    $('#button').addClass('myClass');
   $('#btnSendMailClone').css("margin-right", "100px")
    $('#btnSendMailClone').css("width", "98");
```

And by clicking on the event it should come on its click event

```
function btnSendMail_Click() {
           debugger;

        }
```

Button i debug its giving me error on this line

document.body.appendChild(button);

it says unable to get property append child.I am newbie to java script.Pleas guide what i am doing wrong

Comment: if you are using jquery, why can't you try $('#btnSendMailClone').click(function(){}); instead of writing a seperate function?

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Dynamic button with click event in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707074/creating-dynamic-button-with-click-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I think you document not ready to append .Try with append button after `document.ready` .And don't forget to add jquery link

**Updated**

center position button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var button = document.createElement('input');
  button.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
  button.setAttribute('ID', 'btnSendMailClone');
  button.setAttribute('value', 'Submit');
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'btnSendMail_Click()');
  button.setAttribute('form', 'myform');
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
  $('#button').addClass('myClass');
  $('#btnSendMailClone').addClass('center')

})

function btnSendMail_Click() {
  console.log($('input')[0].outerHTML)
}
```

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 98px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can button come in center because here margin left right is not working

Comment: @janakgera You are using `margin-right` instead of `margin-left`

Comment: @janakgera margin not more effect with button center position try with some transfrom property exact center in horizontal.see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine

```js
var button = document.createElement('input');
button.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
button.setAttribute('ID', 'btnSendMailClone');
button.setAttribute('value', 'Submit');
button.setAttribute('onclick', 'btnSendMail_Click()');
button.setAttribute('form', 'myform');
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
$('#button').addClass('myClass');
$('#btnSendMailClone').css("margin-right", "100px")
$('#btnSendMailClone').css("width", "98");

function btnSendMail_Click() {
  console.log("Submit !");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Possible problem A

Your are using IE then you will have to replace

```
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(button);
```

## Possible problem B

Your script is inside the `<head>`. This will execute the script before the `<body>` has been seen by the browser. To solve this, move your script at the end of the document

Or your can use `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Answer (score 0):

You have got many options.
One simple Solution would be to test if body exists using:

```
if(document.body != null){ document.body.appendChild(button); }
```

Another Option would be to use it by selecting the tag name:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(button);
```

For dynamic manipulation you should have a deep look on jQuery:

```
$('body').append(button);
or
$('body').html(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on last line of your code it seems you are using jQuery, therefore I suggest you to create the button with it like :

```
var button = $('<button type="submit" id="btnSendMailClone" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:100px:width:98%">Submit</button>');
button.on('click',btnSendMail_Click):
$('body').append(button);
```

hope it helps