# Can't dynamically add input type button using Javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to add a javascript button dynamically in ASP.NET MVC using JQuery.Uploadifive js library. When I try to run it, the button is not visible.

My code where I'm trying to add the button:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

        $("#imgUploader").fileUpload({
            'buttonClass': 'btnClass',
            'buttonText': 'Upload Image',
            'uploadScript': '@Url.Content("~/Upload/Upload/")',           
            'multi': false,
            'auto': true,
            'height': 30,
            'width': 100, 
            'onSelect': function (event, ID, fileObj) {
                $.blockUI({ message: '<h2><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loader.gif")" /><br/> Uploading Image...</h2>' });
            }
            , 'onUploadComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response) {
               // debugger;
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Code where I've to add the button:

```
<div class="TextPhoto">
                <div id="imgUploader">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707074/creating-dynamic-button-with-click-event-in-javascript

Comment: also, this link https://www.techiedelight.com/dynamically-generate-input-type-button-javascript/