# How to get dynamic ID of a button in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have written below code of HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
<li><button type="button" id="1" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
<li><button type="button" id="2" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
<li><button type="button" id="3" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
<li><button type="button" id="4" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
...............................

<li><button type="button" id="100" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to fetch particular id in jQuery. But it's not working.

```
$('.highlight').on('click', function(e){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(id); 
});
```

**Edit** added snippet to show code works fine:

```js
$('.highlight').on('click', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><button type="button" id="1" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
  <li><button type="button" id="2" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
  <li><button type="button" id="3" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
  <li><button type="button" id="4" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
  <li><button type="button" id="100" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It should work, try to use `console.log(id)` in place of `alert(id)`, could it be that you have alerts disabled?

Comment: @user2314737 `console.log(id)`  not working.

Comment: You code, as provided, works fine.  I've added a snippet to confirm.   There could be a number of reasons - first **check browser console for errors** such as `$ not defined` - if any errors, report back here with details.  Second, you may be building the `ul` after your `.click(()=>` code has run - `$(".highlight")` will only work on elements that exist at the time the code runs.   Try `$(document).on("click", ".highlight", function() { console.log(this.id); })` - does that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try here and see that your code is working

```js
$('.highlight').on('click', function(e){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(id); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
<li><button type="button" id="1" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
<li><button type="button" id="2" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
<li><button type="button" id="3" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
<li><button type="button" id="4" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
<li><button type="button" id="100" class="highlight"> Edit </button> </li>
</ul>
```

If the button is dynamically added, make sure to do it this way : [Creating Dynamic button with click event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707074/creating-dynamic-button-with-click-event-in-javascript)